# How to convert real altitude and longitude values to GeometryTransform.TransformBox values

Tags: c#, geometry-conversion, sharpmap

I have  a running program which has a point  but its values are not dynamic .

Current code for the point is

```
 var mathTransform = LayerTools.Wgs84toGoogleMercator.MathTransform;
            GeoAPI.Geometries.Envelope geom = GeometryTransform.TransformBox(
                new Envelope(-9.205626, 300.123736, -31.690993, 100.740837),
                mathTransform);
```

Now I want to make a point from altitude and longitude  values to this format how can i  convert.

Comment: altitude = latitude? The values listed in the new Envelope don't make sense for either latitude-longitude or Google Mercator.

Comment: You had tags for QGIS and ArcGIS for Desktop but make no mention of their connection to the question that you are asking so I have removed them.

Comment: @mkennedy sorry  i need to know how can i make a point form latitude  and longitude.

Comment: @mkennedy can you tell me what are the values in the envelope?

Comment: I have no idea! If they are (min lat, min lon, max lat, max lon), the min/max are backwards. If Envelope is (min x, max x, min y, max y), the max y value is too large for a latitude value. If they're actually projected coordinates (in meters or feet), they're too small for most projected coordinate systems.